# С++ Объект удалён, но добраться можно, почему так?

Tags: c++

```
class A 
    { 
    public: 
        int d = 4; 
    }; 
    
    int main( )
{
    A *a = new A(); 
    cout << a->d << endl; 
    A* p = &(*a); 
    delete a; 
    p->d = 5; 
    a->d=3;
    cout << a->d << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Поясните пожалуйста этот код. По какой причине p->d работает даже после удаления a? То есть после delete если сразу вывести p->d, там будет мусорное значение.

Верно ли я понимаю, что p попросту указывает на некоторую область памяти, и компилятор(при создании указателя) "узнал", как обрабатывать выражения типа p->d, и дальше ему уже без разницы, есть ли там реально какой-то объект, к которому мы собираемся обращаться другим способом?

И дальше в коде p можно продолжать использовать как указатель на объект? или мы рискуем получить какие-то конфликты с памятью?

Что именно делает delete? Вопрос задан с целью разобраться, что именно происходит. Прилагаю ассемблерный код.

```
A::A() [base object constructor]:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 4
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     edi, 4
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     rbx, rax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbx], 0
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    A::A() [complete object constructor]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rbx
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-32], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L3
        mov     esi, 4
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
.L3:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-32]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 5
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 3
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))
        mov     eax, 0
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        leave
        ret
__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        jne     .L7
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 65535
        jne     .L7
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
        call    __cxa_atexit
.L7:
        nop
        leave
        ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     esi, 65535
        mov     edi, 1
        call    __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Comment: Вы прекрасно знаете, что нельзя переходить дорогу на красный свет светофора. Вы переходите на красный и спрашиваете: а что это я остался жив и даже не ранен? Верно ли я понимаю, что можно перебегать дорогу на красный? Я могу и дальше перебегать на красный? Или я рискую получить какие-то неприятности?

Comment: Я вам больше скажу, если вы просто удалите объект и потом обратитесь по удаленному указателю, не сохраняя его в отдельной переменной, тоже может сработать. У меня так где-то полгода из-за невнимательности такая фигня в коде жила, причем в постоянно используемой ветке. Ни одного краша. Но это не означает, что так можно. Обращение по удаленному указателю это UB. Может сломаться, может не сломаться. Может отформатировать диск. Может вылететь демон из носа. Все возможно.

Comment: Harry, я не спрашиваю, могу ли я и дальше писать такой код, я хочу разобраться, что в нём именно происходит.

Dearded Beaver, но на самом деле, на уровне ассемблера/машинного кода там всё-таки что-то происходит. Исходно я задался вопросом, а что же в точности означают слова "удаление объекта".

Comment: Происходит обращение к памяти, где *был* объект. Память эта в данный момент никому не принадлежит, никак не задействована (если не сработал, например, другой поток многопоточной программы). Поэтому что в ней находилось — так и находится. Но это никоим образом никто не может *гарантировать*...

Comment: менеджер памяти выдаёт память по-странично ( 4K ) и выдаёт право пользователю её использовать. На эту страницу может поместиться много объектов и вы можете например выходить за границы массива и вам ничего не будет. *Пока за пределы границы страницы памяти не дойдёте.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это работает только из-за того, что вам повезло. Судя по всему перед этим куском памяти был другой кусок, который принадлежал вашему процессу. Потому менеджер памяти ничего вам не сказал. Был бы перед этим куском памяти другой кусок памяти, который бы принадлежал другому процессу - вам бы не удалось ничего в него записать (Это можно сделать, но не так).

Comment: *Это работает только из-за того, что вам повезло* Мне кажется, что наоборот — **не** повезло. Везет — это когда ошибка проявляется сразу, а не маскируется и потом выплывает через полгода в совершенно ином месте...

Comment: Тоже верно, но с таким же успехом я могу сказать, что ему повезло, что код просто скомпилировался @Harry

Comment: Эх, вот если бы семантически неверный код еще и не компилировался... :)

Comment: Эхх, мечты.. Надеюсь, что мы доживём до этого момента.. @Harry

Comment: delete a; 
    p->d = 5; 
    a->d=3;  
    cout << a->d << endl;  
    return 0;

Даже вот это компилируется и выводит что и должно. Я просто в таком случае не очень понимаю, что означает термин "удалить объект". Он просто означает, что ранее занимаемая им память возвращена системе/другому процессу, и всё? Что именно делает delete в этом коде?

Это весь код, а не часть.

Comment: Harry, скажите пожалуйста, что вы имеете в виду, говоря "семантически неверный"?

Comment: Формально вызывает деструктор (в данном случае его нет) + отдает память менеджеру памяти. "Семантически неверный" — это значит, что он соответствует правилам грамматики языка, но делает, грубо говоря, ерунду...

Comment: Ясно, спасибо .

Comment: Оперативная память не резиновая, и всё работает по принципу кредита. Только проценты тут никто не платит. Взял память? - потом отдашь. Вы ничего не удаляете, а лишь говорите менеджеру памяти, что этот кусок вам больше не нужен, и его может использовать кто-то другой @pesoves